# DataGrid.ItemsSource returning old data when I need the edited version

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've searched for a while but I feel like everyone that has similar questions are working with databases or requiring other special circumstances. If i'm just misunderstanding then I apologize for the repeat question.

I have a DataGrid.ItemsSource that I set equal to List<(Entry)> -() where entry is a struct of three strings.

Everything works perfectly and the DataGrid shows everything correctly. However, I intended to allow the user to edit the data in each cell as they please and press a "Save" button to save that data back into a List<(Entry)>. Unfortunately it seems that the old ItemsSource is still there.

So... How do I access the new data? Here is my code. EntryGrid is my DataGrid.

```
public struct Entry
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

private void createTable()
{
    List<Entry> data = new List<Entry>();
    data.Add(new Entry() { Description = "StackOverflow", Username = "TieRein", Password = "LetMeIn" });
    data.Add(new Entry() { Description = "AnotherStackOverflow", Username = "NewTieRein", Password = "DontLetMeIn" });
    EntryGrid.ItemsSource = data;
}

private void SaveFile(bool confirmation)
{
    EntryGrid.Items.Refresh();
    List<Entry> Save = new List<Entry>();
    Save = (List<Entry>)EntryGrid.ItemsSource;
    string filename = "../../../" + m_profile;
    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(filename))
    {
        var writer = new BinaryFormatter();
        writer.Serialize(file, Save);         
    }

    if (confirmation)
        MessageBox.Show("Account Saved");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a list of structs for your data and they are passed by value. When your binding updates the data it will not modify you original struct but some copy of the struct somewhere in the binding implementation.

Use a class to hold your data:

```
public class Entry
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I had no idea a class would make all the difference. This is exactly what I needed and such an easy fix! Looks like I need to reevaluate my understanding of the C# language. Thank you!